# Is it possible to get google photos album sharable url without creating the album?

Tags: php, google-photos-api

I'm creating an app to show all the Google Photos albums of an account (like a gallery) and I want everyone to be able to access the album via a link. I create the albums directly in Google Photos and make them public (creating a sharing link).

I already set up the authentication via Oauth2.0 and created a photosLibraryClient. I am able to get all the albums, their ID's, their names, their cover photo, ... But I can just get it's link but not the shareable one (the public).

I read about the sharing options in the API documentation: https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/share-media

But, as far as I undertood, you can only retrieve a sharing Url if you created the album via the app.

I'm listing albums like this:

```php
$photosLibraryClient->listAlbums()
```

I'm not sure if there is any accessible attribute or method that I don't know here...

I also tried to access the ShareInfo:

```php
$albumUrl = $photosLibraryClient->shareAlbum($album->getId())->getShareInfo()->getShareableUrl();
```

But i get the error:

`NO PERMISSION TO SHARE THIS ALBUM SINCE IT WAS NOT CREATED BY THIS APP`

Any ideas on what to do?

Comment: Sounds like Google very deliberately did not make this possible. _If_ you were to find any way around this restriction, I guess Google would probably consider that a bug that needs fixing. I don’t think you have much of a choice here other than to let your users get the links themselves from their own account dashboards, and copy&paste them into your app, if you really need this kind of feature.

Comment: 3 years later I'm still struggling with the same problem.

Why Google wouldn't let the app get all the public links (if they are already public)? It seems pretty useful feature and a feasable scenario: Create a gallery of my own albums that anyone can see without authentication or asking for a shared link (and getting the album shared, which is something i don't really want to).

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. In the Google Issue Tracker there's a couple of people asking for this same feature. One issue it's still marked as new though it's from 2019. The other one is closed due to "intended behaviour".

We'll have to wait until more people wants this feature or people at Google decide to make it available. Until then, I'll have to manually add a new record to a DB (with a table made for this single purpose) everytime I upload a new album...